# Number of distributions of $r$ distinct objects into $n$ different boxes

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

> Find an exponential generating function for the number of distributions of $r$ distinct objects into $n$ different boxes w/ exactly $m$ nonempty boxes

I'm not sure about the solution, but this is what I obtained after using some identities:
$$
(e^x - 1)^m (1)^{n-m}.
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: The question is not clear: you have $r$, $n$ and $m$ in the question; do you want the generating funcion in three variables, or do you want to keep (say) $n$ and $m$ fixed and consider the generating function's exponents to mark $r$?